# How to apply Multiple Ranks In Tableau?

Tags: hierarchy, tableau-api, ranking

Can Anybody help me with the following Ranking problem in Tableau?

I have a Main Application: XYZ under this Main Application I have multiple Application ID say A,B,C,D,E,F. Now under these Application IDs I have multiple Function IDs say  App ID A has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7: App ID B has 7,8,9,0 and so on.

Now what I need is Rank the Application ID and Rank the Function IDs under those Application IDs by a count if usernames. Till now what I have achieved is only the ranking of Function IDs.

Desperatelty need help!!

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear what you are trying to achieve from your description. If you could provide your example raw data in a table structure and based off that what you would like to achieve.